# How can I convert object HTMLButtonElement to html button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi I get **object HTMLButtonElement**
due to `var btn = document.createElement('button');` this is normal behaviour
but how can I get normal button as an graphic instead of object?
i.e `<button type="button">`

like a converting object into a string but in this case
object to what?

Comment: What's wrong with the object? Do you need to convert it to HTML or something? Usually you can just use the object though.

Comment: I want to display a button what props can I use?

Comment: do you want to get the html markup for the button, in that case `btn.outerHTML`

Comment: If you want to display a button then append the `btn` instance to an element

Comment: It's possible to convert the object to HTML, but most of the time there's no reason to, and the object is much easier and flexible to work with.

Comment: just like https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xq1n18sy/1/

Comment: thx @Arun this is a solution

I wanted this way because I have in the list of products:
here is parameter **object HTMLButtonElement**
i.e milk **object HTMLButtonElement**
that's why I wanted normal button as an graphic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the dom, [Button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) is stored as instances of [HTMLButtonElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement) object, that is why when you try to convert it to string(calling `toString()`) you are getting `[object HTMLButtonElement]`.

Since you want to add the button to the view(dom tree), you can just append the button instance to the tree using [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) like

```js
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerText = 'this button';
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(btn);
document.getElementById('markup').innerText = btn.outerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<pre id="markup"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of element use element.HTML ....such properties like .HTML , .value , .Text
will not return object htmlbuttonelement .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).